# regarding using of Property sheets VS 2008 c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

I am trying to run a project in c++ using visual studio 2008... in vc++ . Now I have a sample project which takes care of the additional included libraries and some other settings... I want to import these settings into my new project. I tried to save the settings of sample project and include them in mine. But I can't see those properties in my new project. 
for eg. sample project displays the linker->input->additional dependencies as cv210d.lib cvaux210d.lib highgui210d.lib cxcore210d.lib cvblobslib.lib but the same thing in my new project shows blank... 
**CAn you please give me the steps for linking properties??** 
What I did was save the property page and then added existing property page in my new project.. That doesn't help

Comment: Perhaps those links answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/377075/visual-c-2008-how-to-have-global-settings-defined-in-a-solution/377988#377988

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3009920/220636

Answer (score 0):

This is maybe not exactly what you wanted, but you can fix this problem by just copying the stuff you want (`cv210d.lib cvaux210d.lib highgui210d.lib cxcore210d.lib cvblobslib.lib`) into the blank space in your project. It's editable, you know what should be there, so just go ahead and put it there.

I guess this will only solve one problem (link dependencies) and you want to solve all such problems by importing. How to do the latter i don't know.